# Unable to access the custom attribute across the project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two different projects in a solution and have the following attribute in the base project(P1). When I use the [INIT] attribute in any of the methods in (P1) it works fine, That is before any method executes it will run the OnEntry() and OnExit() before exiting, but it is not working when I apply it in the methods that are in the project (P2)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Module)]
public class INIT : Attribute, IMethodDecorator
{
    public void OnEntry()
    {
        //some code here
    }
    public void OnExit()
    {
       //some code here

    }
    public void OnException(Exception exception)
    {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

The following code is inside the project (P2) and the INIT attribute applied is not working please Help!
NOTE: P2 has a reference to P1

```
public class LoginToPCM_31463 
    {
        [INIT]
        public static void SmokeTest_LoginToPCMApplication_31463(RemoteWebDriver Driver)
        {
            try
            {
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank You Got the solution-- Was able to access the INIT attribute in (P2)
Solution: Removed namespace for INIT and decorated as [module : INIT] in (P1) project and using the [module: INIT] in (P2) it worked.

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'. Are you getting an error message? And are they in the same namespace or have a reference to one?

Comment: No errors, They are in different projects. When I apply the attribute in the method i.e present in another project - It won't work

Comment: Does project P2 has a reference to P1? It should.

Comment: Yes P2 has a reference to P1.

Comment: The please elaborate on the "Not working" part. How do you invoke OnEntry, OnExit methods? Using a query to get custom attributes?

Comment: I need not invoke it in the Project (P1) as it will automatically execute for all the methods having [INIT]. But the problem is for those methods in Project (P2) that has a reference to (P1)

Comment: The attribute will never "automatically" do anything. Something in the code is looking for the attribute and doing something if it finds the attribute. Whatever that is, it's in one project but not the other.

Comment: Yes, you are correct it was the Fody API doing the trick here.